# How do i select an element with certain ID and a certain rel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at selectors and has attribute seems to be the closes choice however i cant seem to make it work.

what i am trying to do i select an element with certain id that also has a certain rel value..

for example:

```
<input value="Needthisvalue" rel="15" value=wahtever" id="pickthisID" type="hidden">
```

to find out that input with that id and that rel. what I've tried so far is :

TabID contain the 15.

```
$('#pickthisID[rel="'+TabID+'"]').val();
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique in HTML, so using REL is redundant.

Comment: yes i know but in my case it aint.

Comment: Then you have an error in your HTML

Comment: You're setting yourself up for a whole world of pain later on.

Comment: If your IDs aren't unique you have a larger problem. jQuery probably won't work correct with id selectors in that case. If you cannot generate unique IDs, drop the ID entirely and uses classes instead.

Comment: what i have is a part that have  tabs , in those tabs there are more divs. the first div 's id always have the same id for all the tabs

Comment: Not necessarily, it could perhaps be some kind of a check: do X to Y element, but only if Z attribute has *this* value.

Comment: well i will try getting the IDs to be unique and see how this works.  Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your id's have to be unique, otherwise your HTML is erroneous and will throw loads of JS bugs. As for you problem, simply use

```
$('#pickthisID[rel='+a+']').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is optimized so that, if you provide an ID selector (e.g. `#pickthisID`), it will stop looking after its found the first matching element. This is because the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique per page.

However, this would work:

```
$('[id="pickthisID"][rel="'+TabID+'"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by OP, there is an error in your HTML.

```
<input value="Needthisvalue" rel="16"  id="pickthisID" type="hidden">
console.log($('input[rel=16]').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work. But you've some problem with html markup.

You use `value` attribute twice.

```
<input value="Needthisvalue" rel="15" value=wahtever" id="pickthisID" type="hidden">
```

But `value` should one time:

```
<input value="Needthisvalue" rel="15" id="pickthisID" type="hidden">
```

***jQuery***

```
var TabID= 15;
alert( $('#pickthisID[rel='+ TabID +']').val() )
```

**[*DEMO*](http://jsfiddle.net/Tacw4/1/)**

#### Note

`rel` is not valid attribute for `input`. If possible use `data-rel`.